# Is convolution integrable in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, convolution

Let $|h(y)|\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(y)|\,dy<+\infty$.
Consider the function $F(x)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x-y)|\,dy$. It is known that $F(x)$ be bounded and uniformly continuous. I try to find condtitions when $F(x)\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e.
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}F(x)\,dx=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\biggl(\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(x-y)|\,dy\biggr)\,dx<+\infty.
$$
But I can't even find a specific example for that my assumption holds. Is this possible? Because I think $F(x)$ also be an increasing function, so its integral will always divergents.

Comment: When you substitute $z = x-y$ you get basically $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |h(z)| dz \right) dx$, so I wouldn't think it is possible unless $h \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Chris, yes, I see. Indeed, $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(z)|\,dz=\|h\|_{L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\biggl(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|h(z)|\,dz\biggr)\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\|h\|_{L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\,dx=\|h\|_{L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,dx=\infty$.

Comment: $F(x)=F(0).$ Perhaps you wanted to consider $$F(x)=\int h(x-y)g(y)\,dy$$ for two functions $g,h\in L^1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, no-no, I exactly need my conditions. I know that under your assumptions the convolution is integrable.

Comment: @PauldeRenou But your function $F$ is constantly equal $\|h\|_1.$ I do not see anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

No. Indeed, $F(x)\equiv \|h\|_{L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, so that
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}F(x)\,dx=\|h\|_{L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int
\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,dy=\infty.
$$
Thanks for comments to @Chris and @RyszardSzwarc!